# Server name is incorrect with NSwag/OpenApi

Tags: nswag

We have our api hosted at: https://oursitename.com

When we try opening our OpenAPI spec here: https://oursitename.com/openapi/v1/openapi.json, we see that server name specified there is incorrect one: "https://realsitename.azurewebsites.net".

Some additional info: oursitename.com is a CNAME record which points to realsitename.azurewebsites.net. Somehow NSwag shows the latter, even though we access our site through former.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this bug has been fixed in the latest NSwag release.

Comment: This could be a comment, not an answer.